# Dividing algebraic terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am dividing algebraic terms with Wolfram Mathematica.

I understand why it gives me those answers:

$ \frac{2 x}{4 x^2} = \frac{1}{2 x} $

$\frac{2 \text{xy}}{4 \text{xy}} = \frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{2 x^2 y^2}{4 x^3 y^3} = \frac{1}{2 x y}$

$\frac{2 x^2 y^2}{4 x^4 y^4} = \frac{1}{2 x^2 y^2}$

But I do not understand this:

$\frac{2 \text{xy}}{4 x^2 y^2} = \frac{\text{xy}}{2 x^2 y^2}$

Why answer above is $\frac{\text{xy}}{2 x^2 y^2}$ and not $\frac{\text{1}}{2 x y}$ ?

Comment: This might be a question more about WolframAlpha than about math. But I noticed that you wrote $\text{xy}$ instead of $xy$, and I was about to edit your question to correct this, when I realized that this might be the answer!  Perhaps you've convinced Wolfram that $\text{xy}$ is a single variable, not $x$ times $y$; that would explain why it shows up in roman instead of italic type when you copy it and paste it here, and also why Wolfram won't cancel it with $xy$ (although it will cancel it with itself).  Could that be it?

Comment: @TobyBartels You are absolutely right! Thank you. Good catch with difference of font formatting (it is actually Mathematica's output in TeX). I should write `z y` (with space between) and not `xy` because without space Mathematica thinks that it is one variable with name `xy`.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that I saw it before I edited it away!